# Why does double.IsNegative(double.NaN) return true?

Tags: c#, floating-point, double, nan, negative-number

Why does `double.IsNegative(double.NaN)` unexpectedly return `true` whereas `double.NaN < 0` returns `false` as expected?

Comment: Note that another number that is negative, yet `n < 0` returns `false` is `-0.0`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, according to [refrence source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs,fbe1ea23f40e98ce), `double.IsNegative` just checks the **most significant bit**:

```
    [Pure]
    [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
    internal unsafe static bool IsNegative(double d) {
        return (*(UInt64*)(&d) & 0x8000000000000000) == 0x8000000000000000;
    }
```

In case of `double.NaN` the most signifucant bit **is set**:

```
    11111111 11111000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000   
    ||           ||                                                       |
    |<-   Exp   -><-                     Mantissa                        ->
    Sign
```

That's why `double.IsNegative` returns `true`

When we put `<` or `>` *FPU* commands are *used* which know *all ones exponent* is a special kind of floating point value which should be treated in a special way.

The very same picture is with `Single.NaN`.

Note, that we can construct another strange value, *negative zero*:

```
    10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000   
    ||           ||                                                       |
    |<-   Exp   -><-                          Mantissa                   ->
    Sign
```

Please, look:

```
  double negativeZero = BitConverter.ToDouble(new byte[] { 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 128
  });

  Console.WriteLine(negativeZero == 0 ? "Zero" : "???");

  Console.WriteLine(double.IsNegative(negativeZero) ? "Negative" : "???");
```

Comment: @harold: you quite right, thank you! Reversed image is less readable

Comment: Isn't it actually all-ones exponent that is special?  For example all integer powers of 2 such as `1.0`, `256.0`, `0.25` have *all zeros mantissa and non-zero exponent* and they are not special.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Thank you! You are absolutely right, according to IEEE-754 all ones exponent are special kind values

Answer (score 7):

The [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) defines floating point numbers. The highest bit is used to define the sign with 0 being positive and 1 being negative.

Through a bit of digging, `double.NaN` seems to be represented as `0xFFF8000000000000` in binary (and `0.0 / 0.0` in code somehow).

`double.IsNegative(double d)` just checks the highest bit without any actual math being involved. Therefor, NaN is interpreted as a negative value. Meanwhile, `double.NaN` if used in a binary comparison will always yield false:

```cs
double.NaN < 0.0  //false
double.NaN > 0.0  //false
double.NaN <= 0.0 //false
double.NaN >= 0.0 //false
double.NaN == 0.0 //false
```